# Почему Google Adwords ругается на вредоносные ссылки или ПО?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, вирусы, google-adwords

Google Adwords ругается на вредоносные ссылки или ПО. В тех.поддержке написали какие именно ссылки (gistsev-001-sitem-itempurl.com).
В инспекторе кода эти ссылки видны, на слайдере. Но когда захожу в index.html то их там нет.
Насколько я понимаю, это сделано через js?

Сайт http://www.autorent-center.com/

Answer (score 0):

В этом javascript файле http://www.autorent-center.com/js/js.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Header Slider
    function promoSlider() {
        $('#slides').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            fade: true,
            arrows: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 3000,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            pauseOnFocus: false,
            pauseOnHover: false
        });
    }
```

Инициируется слайдер, который вставляет картинки с указанного домена (/js/js.js):

```
//Getting Car data From Server
var server = 'http://gistsev-001-site1.itempurl.com/';
var serverManage = server + "Management/";
var serverImg = "http://gistsev-001-site1.itempurl.com/Content/";
```

Имена картинок возвращаются ajax-запросом (в инспекторе видно) с:
http://gistsev-001-site1.itempurl.com/Management/Promoutions

код из /js/js.js:

```
//Promotions section
$.get(serverManage + 'Promoutions')
.done(function (data) {
    var promotions = data.promoutions;
    promotions.forEach(function(promo) {
        promotionRender(promo);
    });
    promoSlider();
})
```

То есть да, это делается javascript'ом.

Похоже, что это ваш же javascript. Поэтому, грузите картинки с другого домена, если гуглу не нравится этот домен.

Comment: То есть, как один из вариантов решения, это изменить ссылки на подгрузку картинок?

Comment: @VadimK, да, было бы лучше с этого же домена autorent-center.com и загружать картинки, на мой взгляд, а не с какого-то стороннего сайта, судя по всему админки :)